# Skipping try catch statements?

Tags: java

I am making a Hangman game and have recently implemented a file reading method to randomize the word; however, I didn't get very far as I tested the file reader before I randomized which line it reads and my code seems to skip the try catch block?
Here is the line from the constructor that uses this method:

```
word = determineWord();
```

And here is the method:

```
String determineWord() {
    String fileName = "HangmanWords.txt";

    String line = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        } 

        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't open file");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");                  
    }
    return line;
}
```

The error I recieve is NullPointerException, I believe because line is initially set as null, and word cannot be null in my program.

Comment: It doesn't skip the try-catch block. But you're reading two lines at each iteration, and you're returning the final value of line, which is always null, since the loop stops when line is null. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JBNizet the while loop checks and sees if there is another line to read. Line should return as the last line in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop reads 2 lines per iteration.

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```

dont readLine() again in the loop body

```
String line = null;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do something about the line
}
```

Comment: i ended up putting finalLine = line in the loop and returning that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Catching Exception is not a good convention at all. It's actually very bad practice. You should only catch exceptions that you can, and intend to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop is incorrect. Its post-condition is `line == null`, which is precisely the state in which your program leaves `line` every time.

You should create a separate variable, and set it to some random `line` from the file.

Here is a simple way to do it, which is not uniform:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

String determineWord() {
    String fileName = "HangmanWords.txt";

    String res = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        int count = 1;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (res == null || 4*rnd.nextInt(count) > count) {
                res = line;
            }
            count++;
        } 

        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't open file");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");                  
    }
    return res;
}
```

Surprisingly, the process is somewhat tricky, unless you know upfront how many lines are there in your text file. See [*reservoir sampling algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) for information on how to do this in a uniform way.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading two times hence after the end of the file null is assigned to line which you are returning. You can do a check before reading or read only once.

```
while(bufferedReader.readLine().hasNext()) {
   line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong: it reads two lines at each iteration instead of just one, and it returns line, which is always null, since that's the condition for the loop to stop. The code should be something like

```
String lastReadLine = null;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lastReadLine = line;
}
return lastReadLine;
```

I would also avoid returning null, or some random line, when there is an error. You shouldn't continue as if nothing happens if there is an exception. Throw it instead of catching it.

And you should make sure the reader is closed, whatever happens. That's what the try-with-resources statement is for:

```
String determineWord() throws IOException {
    String fileName = "HangmanWords.txt";

    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {

        String line = null;
        String lastReadLine = null;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lastReadLine = line;
        }
        return lastReadLine; 
    }
}
```